# React Swiper Slider Navigation not working after built

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have checked other questions and I can confirm that all modules and CSS files are imported correctly.

The next/prev button for Navigation module works correctly when I run it locally via `npm run dev`

And it stops working when I run `npm run build` and `npm run start` to run the built project.

By "stops working", I mean the buttons are there, but clicking them won't do anything. The pagination module still works and user can also drag the images to move left and right. Just the next/prev buttons are not doing anything at all.

Furthermore, when `npm run dev`, the prev/next button will be disabled if there's no more images to show on left/right respectively. But after `npm run build`, they are no longer disabled.

Is there any possibility for this to happen? I tried `npm i` and it seems all packages are installed.

PS. It works on a page, but it does not work inside a modal.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IRootState } from '@/store';
import { isMobileDevice } from '@/components/contains/contants';

export interface CarouselInstagramProps {
    items?: any[];
}

const CarouselInstagram: FC<CarouselInstagramProps> = ({
    items = [],
}) => {

    const themeConfig = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.themeConfig);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('items', items);
    }, [items])

    return (
        <div className='w-full CarouselInstagram'>
            
            <Swiper
                modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
                navigation={{
                    nextEl: '#swiper-button-next-ex1',
                    prevEl: '#swiper-button-prev-ex1',
                }}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                className="swiper mx-auto max-w-3xl w-full"
                id="slider1"
                dir={themeConfig.rtlClass}
                key={themeConfig.rtlClass === 'rtl' ? 'true' : 'false'}
            >
                <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                    {
                        (!items || !Array.isArray(items) || !items.length) &&
                        <SwiperSlide>
                            <img src={'/assets/images/Vertical-Placeholder-Image.png'} className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    }
                    {
                        items && Array.isArray(items) && items.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <SwiperSlide key={i}>
                                    {
                                        item?.mediaType ?
                                        (
                                            item?.mediaType == 1
                                            ?
                                            // Image
                                            <img src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + item?.mediaUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')}
                                            className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                                            :
                                            // Video
                                            (
                                                isMobileDevice() ?
                                                <img className="w-full object-cover"
                                                src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + items[0].thumbnailUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')} />
                                                :
                                                <video className="w-full object-cover" controls>
                                                    <source src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + item?.mediaUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')} type="video/mp4" />
                                                    Sorry, your browser doesn&#39;t support videos.
                                                </video>

                                            )
                                        )
                                        :
                                        (
                                            item?.type != "video/mp4"
                                            ?
                                            // Image
                                            <img src={URL.createObjectURL(item)}
                                            className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                                            :
                                            // Video
                                            <video className="w-full object-cover" controls>
                                                <source src={URL.createObjectURL(item)} type="video/mp4" />
                                                Sorry, your browser doesn&#39;t support videos.
                                            </video>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </SwiperSlide>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <button id="swiper-button-prev-ex1" className="swiper-button-prev-ex1 absolute top-1/2 z-[999] grid -translate-y-1/2 place-content-center rounded-full p-1 transition ltr:left-2 rtl:right-2">
                    <div className=" _9zm0"></div>
                </button>
                <button id="swiper-button-next-ex1" className="swiper-button-next-ex1 absolute top-1/2 z-[999] grid -translate-y-1/2 place-content-center rounded-full p-1 transition ltr:right-2 rtl:left-2">
                    <div className=" _9zm2"></div>
                </button>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CarouselInstagram;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this solution to solve it.

Still unsure why Navigation module stops working after build.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IRootState } from '@/store';
import { isMobileDevice } from '@/components/contains/contants';

export interface CarouselInstagramProps {
    items?: any[];
}

const CarouselInstagram: FC<CarouselInstagramProps> = ({
    items = [],
}) => {

    const themeConfig = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.themeConfig);
    const swiperRef = useRef<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('items', items);
    }, [items])

    return (
        <div className='w-full CarouselInstagram'>
            
            <Swiper
                ref={swiperRef}
                modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                className="swiper mx-auto max-w-3xl w-full"
                id="slider1"
                dir={themeConfig.rtlClass}
                key={themeConfig.rtlClass === 'rtl' ? 'true' : 'false'}
            >
                <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                    {
                        (!items || !Array.isArray(items) || !items.length) &&
                        <SwiperSlide>
                            <img src={'/assets/images/Vertical-Placeholder-Image.png'} className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    }
                    {
                        items && Array.isArray(items) && items.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <SwiperSlide key={i}>
                                    {
                                        item?.mediaType ?
                                        (
                                            item?.mediaType == 1
                                            ?
                                            // Image
                                            <img src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + item?.mediaUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')}
                                            className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                                            :
                                            // Video
                                            (
                                                isMobileDevice() ?
                                                <img className="w-full object-cover"
                                                src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + items[0].thumbnailUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')} />
                                                :
                                                <video className="w-full object-cover" controls>
                                                    <source src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + item?.mediaUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')} type="video/mp4" />
                                                    Sorry, your browser doesn&#39;t support videos.
                                                </video>

                                            )
                                        )
                                        :
                                        (
                                            item?.type != "video/mp4"
                                            ?
                                            // Image
                                            <img src={URL.createObjectURL(item)}
                                            className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                                            :
                                            // Video
                                            <video className="w-full object-cover" controls>
                                                <source src={URL.createObjectURL(item)} type="video/mp4" />
                                                Sorry, your browser doesn&#39;t support videos.
                                            </video>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </SwiperSlide>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => swiperRef && swiperRef.current && swiperRef.current.swiper.slidePrev()} id="swiper-button-prev-ex1" className="swiper-button-prev-ex1 absolute top-1/2 z-[999] grid -translate-y-1/2 place-content-center rounded-full p-1 transition ltr:left-2 rtl:right-2">
                    <div className=" _9zm0"></div>
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => swiperRef && swiperRef.current && swiperRef.current.swiper.slideNext()} id="swiper-button-next-ex1" className="swiper-button-next-ex1 absolute top-1/2 z-[999] grid -translate-y-1/2 place-content-center rounded-full p-1 transition ltr:right-2 rtl:left-2">
                    <div className=" _9zm2"></div>
                </button>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CarouselInstagram;
```